# Как сделать такой вырез треугольника как на макете, чтобы была такая же обводка и видно было изображение

Tags: html, css

Никак не могу разобраться, как сделать такой вырез как в макете. Помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _"Никак не могу разобраться..."_ Пока не видно даже попыток. Приложите разметку и стили. Укажите, в чём именно проблема. _"Помогите, пожалуйста."_ Помочь - это одно, а сделать за Вас - другое.

Comment: Если бы не эта линия внутри по периметру, то задача была бы тривиальной, но с линией придется повозиться. Эконом-вариант - у6ить дизайнера.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Вот именно! ))) Да, сейчас стал прикидывать, эту серую линию псевдоэлементами на раз-два-три, согласен!

Comment: @UModel Делаю сайт на конструкторе, фон сам с border сделать не проблема, картинку тоже, а вот сделать такой вырез еще и прозрачный не получается, пробовал clip-path, но что то с ним не выходит,  Добавляю к блоку через css класс. Если сюда можно скинуть сайт, могу скинуть.

Answer (score 4):

```css
body { margin: 0; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; min-height: 100vh; }

.service {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 340px;
}

.service>img {
  width: 310px; height: 190px;
  object-fit: auto; border-radius: 15px;
}
.service>div {
  box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 15px;
  width: 100%; padding: 65px 25px 45px;
  transform: translatey(-20px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(25deg, #fff 78%, transparent 78.1%), linear-gradient(-25deg, #fff 78%, transparent 78.1%);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px #aaa8) drop-shadow(0 0 1px #aaa8) drop-shadow(-3px -3px 0px #fff) drop-shadow(0px -3px 0px #fff) drop-shadow(3px -3px 0px #fff) drop-shadow(3px 0px 0px #fff) drop-shadow(3px 3px 0px #fff) drop-shadow(0px 3px 0px #fff) drop-shadow(-3px 3px 0px #fff) drop-shadow(-3px 0px 0px #fff) drop-shadow(0px 10px 10px #0003);
}

.service ul { width: 100%; margin: 65px 0 0; }
.service li { font: normal 16px/1em sans-serif; margin: 0.5em 0; }

.service>div>div { text-align: center; }
.service h2 { font: bold 28px/1em serif; margin: 0; }
.service h3 { font: normal 18px/1em sans-serif; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="service">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9kuJ.jpg" alt="">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>Поклейка</h2>
      <h3>всех видов обоев</h3>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Выезд замерщика</li>
      <li>Устранение дефектов</li>
      <li>Поклейка обоев</li>
      <li>Вынос мусора</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Гениально! Я бы не догадался=)

Comment: @ДавидМанжула: спасибо, но насчёт гениальности, такое себе... Просто технологии не стоят на месте, и мы тоже должны успевать за ними :)

Comment: @UModeL Спасибо вам огромное, очень выручили.

Comment: @IwillNotDIe: только сверьтесь с поддержкой браузерами.